# meteor application crashing

Tags: web-applications, meteor, crash

I got this error when trying to start the app:

```
    enteW20150911-13:17:04.497(2)? (STDERR)           W20150911-13:17:04.498(2)? (STDERR) /home/sanchezj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.st5tu4++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
W20150911-13:17:04.498(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150911-13:17:04.498(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150911-13:17:04.498(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined
W20150911-13:17:04.498(2)? (STDERR)     at app/github_microscope/server/fixtures.js:6:28
W20150911-13:17:04.499(2)? (STDERR)     at app/github_microscope/server/fixtures.js:74:3
W20150911-13:17:04.499(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/sanchezj/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150911-13:17:04.499(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150911-13:17:04.499(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/sanchezj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.st5tu4++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
r code here
W20150911-13:17:10.424(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150911-13:17:10.424(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150911-13:17:10.427(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: Cannot call method 'insert' of undefined
W20150911-13:17:10.428(2)? (STDERR)     at app/github_microscope/server/fixtures.js:6:28
W20150911-13:17:10.428(2)? (STDERR)     at app/github_microscope/server/fixtures.js:74:3
W20150911-13:17:10.428(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/sanchezj/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:222:10
W20150911-13:17:10.429(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150911-13:17:10.429(2)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/sanchezj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.st5tu4++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150911-13:17:10.429(2)? (STDERR)     at /home/sanchezj/microscope/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:117:5
=> Exited with code: 8
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I read some similar questions and some proposed solutions as adding iron-router package and some similar operations to that package but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: Looks like you're running Microscope (https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope).  The error is pointing to line 6 of the fixtures file, which is an insert into the Meteor.users collection.  Did you remove the `accounts-password` package that comes with Microscope?  Try `meteor add accounts-password` then restart meteor.

Comment: Probably a load order problem. Where are your collections defined in your directory structure?

Comment: @MarkLeiber I am running Microscope yes. Well.. I have not removed anything since I am following the Tutorial. Anyway, I tried to run the code that you suggest me and it appears another error , now is this: 

Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
/home/sanchezj/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.4.st5tu4++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
      throw(ex);
            ^
Error: A method named '/posts/insert' is already defined

So It is just after dong git clone when I have this problem

Comment: @corvid Actually I have not defined it yet.

Comment: @Javiss: if you run `git status` do you have any changes or is it up-to-date with master?

Comment: @MarkLeiber # On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: @Javiss: Do you have the Microscope code cloned inside a directory that also has a .meteor folder?  It looks like you probably have your app/.meteor folder and app/github_microscope/.meteor.

Comment: @MarkLeiber yes! I have the structure as you said. I just cloned it in another different folder than the project itself and it runs certainly! I might misunderstood the way to cloned because I thought I had to cloned there.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you created a project:

```
meteor create yourproject
cd yourproject
```

And then you cloned the Microscope project inside of it:

```
git clone https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope.git
```

When you ran your initial `meteor create` statement, meteor created a `.meteor` folder for you.  This folder stores important information about the packages used in the application.

If you look at the Microscope code that you cloned, it already contains a `.meteor` folder: https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/tree/master/.meteor

In general, when checking in meteor projects to version control systems, you should include the `.meteor` folder so that it can be easily cloned and run without having to figure out what packages are supposed to be installed.

So to correctly run Microscope, you just need to clone it into a new directory (not nested inside an existing meteor directory), `cd` into the directory, and run `meteor`.

I have seen the occasional project that has been checked in without a `.meteor` folder.  In those cases, they generally have a README file that instructs you to start your own project (using `meteor create yourproject`) and to install a specific list of packages that they provide (`meteor install package1 package2 ...`).

Always look for the presence of the `.meteor` folder in the repo.  If it's there, don't create your own project.  If it's not there, create your own and clone into it.